# how to use bespin commands on embedded bespin?

Tags: javascript, bespin

I set my embedded bespin as below, which works good:

```
_editorComponent = new bespin.editor.Component('editor', {
    language        : my_language,
    loadfromdiv     : true,
    set             : {
        fontsize        : 10,
        tabsize         : 4,
        highlightline   : 'on'
    }
});
```

and html part for this:

```
 <div id='editor'>some code...</div>
```

By following embedded bespin's code, i was able to find out getContent and setContent, however i couldnt find anything on Bespin documentation for further implementations of Bespin.

Is there anyone who knows how to add search and replace functionality to it? for example from above instance:

```
_editorComponent.searchText("some_string");
_editorComponent.replaceText("some_string","another_string");
_editorComponent.focusText("some_string");
```

Do we have such commands on bespin, which i can use on my application?

**Edit**: *Response to same question on google groups:*

> There was some support for
>   search once upon a time in Bespin, but
>   it's not back to the rebooted Bespin
>   yet. But it's definitely one of the
>   features on my to-be-implemented list
>   ;)

So this can only be done with workarounds for now, any workaround is more than welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: response to same question on google groups:

> There was some support for search once upon a time in Bespin, but it's
>   not back to the rebooted Bespin yet. But it's definitely one of the
>   features on my to-be-implemented list ;)